# USB mode MMX352G is not detected in Ubuntu12.10 though installed gnome-ppp

Tags: usb-modem

I am using micromax 352G usb modem.Ubuntu 12.10 is not detecting it as a modem device though it has shown it by the command "lsusb". After running "gnome-ppp", it shows an error report that /etc/modem have not been found.

Plz help...

Answer (score 1):

same here.

I used to have faced the same issue.

In `12.04LTS` it got detected as `usb` device and after ejecting the usb device it got detected as modem.

But the problem in 12.10 is that the `usb` device is not showing.

So I got a little trick for that.

> > just log into win7/xp first and insert the modem. Restart the computer
> >     and then  log into ubuntu. but keep in mind that dont disconnect or
> >     eject the modem from pc and dont switch off the main power.
>
> Doing so You have to do the process again.

Works fine for me.
Actually I am connected to the internet using that same modem.
Best of luck and let me know the result.